# ffmpeg output to S3 using PUT presigned url - not seeing output file on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, ffmpeg, pre-signed-url

I am creating a PUT presigned url and using it to upload ffmpeg output to S3. I am not getting any error but not seeing output files on S3 bucket.

Using below ffmpeg command to upload a file.

C:>ffmpeg.exe -re -i in.ts -f hls -method PUT "https://server.com/bucket/object/out.m3u8?AWSAccessKeyId=accessKey&Expires=123456789&Signature=signature"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Logs: [hls @ 0000020f1b956380] Opening 'https://server.com/bucket/object/out0.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0000020f1b956380] Opening 'https://server.com/bucket/object/out1.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0000020f1b956380] Opening 'https://server.com/bucket/object/out2.ts' for writing
frame= 1889 fps= 15 q=27.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:02:05.93 bitrate=N/A speed=0.999x
video:1735kB audio:5259kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown. Not seeing any error, ffmpeg opened an output for writing but no output file has been uploaded to S3 bucket.

Comment: Do no if its related but remove `-re`.

Comment: HLS requires multiple files, the presigned URL is good for one object only, so while it's odd ffmpeg isn't erroring out, this can't work.  You need to find some other way to transfer the segments, either via something like s3fs, or just creating local files then syncing them up.

Comment: @AnonCoward I tried with MP4 file also, but ffmpeg won't be able to update headers since it's non seekable. I tried with different file types, all are errored except HLS. My requirement is to upload file directly to S3 without a local copy. When I ran the cmd, no errors and from logs I can see that it's opening to write each HLS stream to presignedurl but I couldn't see any files in s3 bucket.[hls @ 0000012dcd4f6680] Opening 'https://localhost:9000/media/procedure1/output0.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0000012dcd4f6680] Opening 'https://localhost:9000/media/procedure1/output1.ts' for writing...so on

Comment: Then you need to use something like s3fs.  Regardless of what you see in the console, it's not technically possible to use one presigned URL to upload different objects.